# Two unlinked lists, finding position of item in one and printing the positions from the other

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

So I was given an assignment to webscrape off a website. I have two lists, one containing quotes and the other of who said the quotes. I was told to print the quotes Albert Einstein said. So I have code to find the positions of when Albert Einstein comes up in the first list and I've been trying to print off the quotes in the same positions as when Albert Einstein comes up. I've been stuck on this for two days now and it's to be handed in later, please help :)

error message - StopIteration

```
import requests 
import bs4

res = requests.get("http://quotes.toscrape.com/") 

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml') 
all_author = []
all_quote = []
for element in soup.select('small'):
    all_author.append(element.text)
for element in soup.select('span'):
    all_quote.append(element.text) 


g = (i for i, n in enumerate(all_author) if n == 'ALbert Einstein')

for x in all_quote:
    print (all_quote.index(next(g)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the list comprehension to get all the indices and then print the quotes according to each index:

```
g = [i for i, n in enumerate(all_author) if n == 'Albert Einstein']
for i in g:
    print(all_quote[i])
```

However there are unwanted strings in `all_quote` such that, `len(all_author)!=len(all_quote)`. You can filter the elements when filling the list e.g.:

```
all_quote = []
for element in soup.select('span'):
    t = element.text
    if t[0] == '“' and t[-1] == '”':
        all_quote.append(t)
```

Comment: this fixed the error message but I mustve mucked the code up somewhere else because its not outputting anything

Comment: There is a typo in the list comprehension ('L' instead of 'l' in Albert).
However you also have the problem that `len(all_author)!=len(all_quote)` . There seems to be some weird strings in all_quote, so you will need to filter it to contain only the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to find out the position of the author and then use that position to pick the quotes from quotes list

```
quotes = ['hope', 'faith', 'welcome']
author = ['einstein','tesla','einstein']
indices = [ i for i, x in enumerate(author) if x == 'einstein']
author_quote = [ quotes[index] for index in indices]
```